# Determine if a body has collided - Cocos2d/Box2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Is it possible to determine if a b2body has collided with another b2body from a different layer? Also, how would I do that?

E.G.

I have a ball on my main game scene layer that is fired at a bomb in my level one layer. They collide and the bomb disappears.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want bodies to collide they must belong to the same b2World. On what layer they are drawn and how does not matter to the physics. To determine when collision happens subclass `b2ContactListener` and implement callback functions:

```
class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
public:
MyContactListener() : b2ContactListener() {}

void    BeginContact (b2Contact *contact);
void    EndContact (b2Contact *contact);
void    PreSolve (b2Contact *contact, const b2Manifold *oldManifold);
void    PostSolve (b2Contact *contact, const b2ContactImpulse *impulse);

};
```

then add the object of this class to your b2World:

```
MyContactListener *listener = new MyContactListener();
world->SetContactListener(listener);
```

Comment: I have the collision detection setup. Should I just globally declare the b2World? The ball is drawn on the game scene layer which is it's own class and the bomb is drawn on the level one layer which is it's own class.

Comment: @Jon: I think you have the main scene or layer that contains all other layers. You can store b2World pointer their and pass pointer to it to every child layer you create

Comment: @Jon: myLayer->addChild(childLayer)